# Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to EnderPearl

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit, type-mismatch

Okay so, I have a problem... The title basically explains the error. But I have no idea on how to fix it. So would be glad if you could help me.

```
          if (cause == PlayerTeleportEvent.TeleportCause.ENDER_PEARL)
      {
        ArrayList pearls = (ArrayList)this.ender.get(e.getPlayer());

          if (pearls != null)
          {
              Location to = e.getTo();
              for (EnderPearl p : pearls) //**Error is here. ("pearls")**
              {
                  if ((p != null) && (p.getLocation().distanceSquared(to) < 2.0D))
                  {
                      pearls.remove(p);
                      e.setCancelled(true);
                      return;
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
```

Comment: Solution: Don't use raw types.

Comment: Your arraylist contains objects.  You need to cast to EnderPearl, unless the real collection is of type `ArrayList<EnderPearl>`

Comment: ArrayList<EnderPearl> pearls ?

Comment: Yeh haha, didn't realise. Thanks guys. I fixed it by just doing like u said: Changed it to: ArrayList<EnderPearl> pearls = blablabla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you use raw types where you you would be better off using the following code to define your array list:

```
ArrayList<EnderPearl> pearls = (ArrayList)this.ender.get(e.getPlayer());
```

And then you don't have to worry about casting or anything!